# scrapy: newbie attempting to debug code

Tags: python, scrapy

Total newbie, trying to get scrapy to read a list of urls from csv and return the items in a csv.
Need some help to figure out where I'm going wrong here:
Spider code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
import random

class incyspider(BaseSpider):
    name = "incyspider"
    def __init__(self):
        super(incyspider, self).__init__()
        domain_name = "incyspider.co.uk"
        f = open("urls.csv")
        start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
        f.close

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="Product"]')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item['title'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="Name"]/node()').extract()
            item['hlink'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="Price"]/node()').extract()
            item['price'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="Codes"]/node()').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items

SPIDER = incyspider()
```

Here's the items.py code:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class incyspider(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = Field()
    title = Field()
    hlink = Field()
    price = Field()
    pass
```

To run, I'm using

```
scrapy crawl incyspider -o items.csv -t csv
```

I would seriously appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you start the crawling process? Look into the Scrapy log files and post here what's in there. We cannot help you without more information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure but after a quick look at your code I would say that at least you need to replace this line

```
sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="Product"]')
```

by this line

```
sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="Product"]').extract()
```

Comment: thankyou - I altered the code, and it looks like the main error now is: "exceptions.NameError: global name 'item' is not defined" apologies if this is basic stuff - last programming I did was in basic on a ZX Spectrum!

Answer (score 1):

As a first punt at answering this, your spider code is missing an import for your `incyspider` item class. Also you're not creating an instance of any kind of item to store the title/hlink/price info, so the `items.append(item)` line might complain.

Since your spider is also called `incyspider`, you should rename the item to be something like `incyspiderItem` and then add the following line to your spider code

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
import random
from incyspider.items import incyspiderItem 

class incyspider(BaseSpider):
    name = "incyspider"
    def __init__(self):
        super(incyspider, self).__init__()
        domain_name = "incyspider.co.uk"
        f = open("urls.csv")
        start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
        f.close

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="Product"]')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = incyspiderItem()
            item['title'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="Name"]/node()').extract()
            item['hlink'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="Price"]/node()').extract()
            item['price'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="Codes"]/node()').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

If I'm wrong, then please edit the question to explain how you know there is a problem with the code eg: is the expected output different to the actual output? If so, how?

Comment: thanks so much - I think I'm getting somewhere now. can I just check - where you've used "from tutorial.items import incyspiderItem" should I replace tutorial with my project name? so "from incy.items import incyspiderItem" for example?

Comment: Excellent. Please remember to accept whichever answer was the most beneficial. :)

Comment: @Mark P: "`obliged` - past tense of o·blige (Verb) 1. Make (someone) legally or morally bound to an action or course of action..." You are not legally bound, but encouraged to accept an answer if it helped you find a solution :)